# Detect mock location in flutter for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps, gps, mock-location

I am using google maps and location package to know the current position of user, and I would like to prevent user for using fake GPS. Right now I build the project for iOS, and I didn't find yet any package to detect whether user using fake GPS or not..
Is there a package that I can use to detect it?

Comment: You can't.  If the fake GPS data is coming from an external hardware device it is indistinguishable from a real GPS feed.  The only other way to fake location on iOS is using debugging tools; again there is no indication that this is happening.  You can try and correlate mobile network identifier with location but this is a very course check and only works on phones

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding here, I would like to detect wether user is using fake gps or not when opening my apps project.. so when user is using my apps, I want to know if user enable their fake gps or not

Comment: As I said, you can't. There are no simple fake gps apps available for iOS. The user either has external hardware pretending to be GPS or they are using Xcode or similar debugging tools to fake the location of the device. Neither of these are detectable by an app

Comment: I just understand what you said, thank you very much @Paulw11 for your explanation.. your explanation helps me so much

Comment: Can you undelete this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329422/keyboard-in-webview-of-ios-flutter-apps-doesnt-show-up The answer there was helpful for me.

Comment: @Suragch I have been undelete.. and I found the answer by doing this: doing "uncheck" in I/O->Keyboard->Toggle software keyboard in my Simulator menu

Comment: [Questions asking to recommend or find an off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)