# keyboard in webview of ios flutter apps doesn't show up

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I am trying to show webview in my ios project apps, so I use webview_flutter 1.0.7 as the plugin, and inside the webview there is textfield and I need to type or input something there... but the keyboard doesn't show up... I have tried to build in android and the keyboard shows up and I can type something.. I get this case only when I launch this apps in ios.. is there a way so that I can type something inside textfield of webview and shows the keyboard ? this question is related to this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25436#issuecomment-649278727 and I have followed it by doing check in I/O->Keyboard->Toggle software keyboard in my Simulator menu, but the keyboard still doesn't show up

Comment: Are you sure it is an issue with Flutter and not your iOS simulator ? Did you try to build it on a physical device ?

Comment: I haven't tried to build in physical device, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The OP solved it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66325756/detect-mock-location-in-flutter-for-ios?noredirect=1#comment117572820_66325756):

> I found the answer by doing this: doing "uncheck" in I/O->Keyboard->Toggle software keyboard in my Simulator menu

And a now deleted (I'm not sure why) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66330186/3681880) by [Guillaume Roux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9942346/guillaume-roux) said:

> Seems like it is an issue coming from your simulator. Try to display the simulator's keyboard using ⌘ + K.